# PHP sessions error

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin, xampp, opencart

I user opencart v2.3.0.2 and after finished my site I use a scanner to scan my website but after while I get this error :

> Fatal error: session_set_save_handler(): Session handler's function
>   table is corrupt in \system\library\session.php on line 16

I have try to add this in my `php.ini`

```
session.save_path = "/temp";
```

but I still get the same error. I use XAMPP.

the session file :

```
<?php
class Session {
    public $session_id = '';
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct($adaptor = 'native') {
        $class = 'Session\\' . $adaptor;

        if (class_exists($class)) {
            $this->adaptor = new $class($this);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Error: Could not load session adaptor ' . $adaptor . ' session!');
        }       

        if ($this->adaptor) {
            session_set_save_handler($this->adaptor);
        }

        if ($this->adaptor && !session_id()) {
            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'Off');
            ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
            ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'On');

            if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-]{22,52}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
                exit('Error: Invalid session ID!');
            }

            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
            session_start();
        }           
    }

    public function start($key = 'default', $value = '') {
        if ($value) {
            $this->session_id = $value;
        } elseif (isset($_COOKIE[$key])) {
            $this->session_id = $_COOKIE[$key];
        } else {
            $this->session_id = $this->createId();
        }   

        if (!isset($_SESSION[$this->session_id])) {
            $_SESSION[$this->session_id] = array();
        }

        $this->data = &$_SESSION[$this->session_id];

        if ($key != 'PHPSESSID') {
            setcookie($key, $this->session_id, ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime'), ini_get('session.cookie_path'), ini_get('session.cookie_domain'), ini_get('session.cookie_secure'), ini_get('session.cookie_httponly'));
        }

        return $this->session_id;
    }   

    public function getId() {
        return $this->session_id;
    }

    public function createId() {
        if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.5.4', '>') == true) {
            return $this->adaptor->create_sid();
        } elseif (function_exists('random_bytes')) {
            return substr(bin2hex(random_bytes(26)), 0, 26);
        } elseif (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
            return substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(26)), 0, 26);
        } else {
            return substr(bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(26, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), 0, 26);
        }
    }

    public function destroy($key = 'default') {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        }

        setcookie($key, '', time() - 42000, ini_get('session.cookie_path'), ini_get('session.cookie_domain'));
    }
}


not important section ://
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla//
```

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the apache & mysql. It will solve the error.